# SQL Server 2012, Generate random date in specific way

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a random appointment in my db.

How can I refactor this code so StartDate can only be given Whole, Half or Quartz minutes and the EndDate adds 1 hour to StartDate?

I am using SQL Server 2012

```
 SELECT            
        (SELECT TOP 1 Id from [dbo].[am_Customer] order by newid()) AS CustomerId
          -- TODO: StartDate can only be given Whole, Half or Quartz hours
       ,(SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 3650), getdate())) AS StartDate
          -- TODO: Need to add 1 hour to StartDate
       ,(SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 3650), getdate())) AS EndDate
       ,(SELECT TOP 1 ServiceName from [dbo].[am_Appointments] 
            WHERE DATALENGTH(ServiceName) > 0  order by newid()) AS ServiceName
       ,(SELECT TOP 1 Id from [dbo].[Employees] order by newid()) AS EmployeeId
```

**EDIT:
Here is the solution i ended up with:**

```
;WITH s AS (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(minute, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 350400)*15,
        DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,getdate()),0)) AS StartDate
)

SELECT            
        (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [dbo].[am_Customer] ORDER BY newid()) AS CustomerId
       ,(SELECT s.StartDate)  AS StartDate
       ,(SELECT DATEADD(hour,1,s.StartDate)) AS EndDate
       ,(SELECT TOP 1 ServiceName from [dbo].[am_Appointments] WHERE DATALENGTH(ServiceName) > 0  ORDER BY newid()) AS ServiceName
       ,(SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [dbo].[Employees] ORDER BY newid()) AS EmployeeId


FROM s
```

Comment: Quartz = Quater? so 60, 30 or 15 minute intervals only - is that correct?

Comment: That is correct @Used_By_Already

Comment: good to see you try it - and succeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate a `StartDate` value some time in the next 10 years that falls on a 15 minute interval, and also an `EndDate` an hour later:

```
;With s as (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(minute, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 350400)*15,
        DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,getdate()),0)) as StartDate
)
select s.StartDate,DATEADD(hour,1,s.StartDate) as EndDate
from s
```

This has a (small) probability of generating a `StartDate` that falls today and before now. If you want to avoid that, the simple fix is to change the second `0` in `DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,getdate()),0))` to a `1`, and then it won't generate any values on today's date.

Comment: Ty for this answere, this is exactly how i want it. But my SQL isen't so good so i cant implement this without loosing my other tables. Can you please show me how to add the ServiceName select to this query.

Comment: take you existing query (as displayed in the question) place it UNDER the CTE "with .... then replace your existing startdate and enddate calculations with the ones provided in the solutions... it is not hard - try it

Answer (score 0):

Use CROSS APPLY to calculate the start date, then that calculation can be referenced by its alias to calculate the end date, like so:

```
|                       STARTDATE |                        COLUMN_1 |
|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|
| February, 25 2020 10:30:00+0000 | February, 25 2020 11:30:00+0000 |
|     July, 08 2018 18:15:00+0000 |     July, 08 2018 19:15:00+0000 |
```

produced by

```
SELECT
      ca1.StartDate
    , dateadd(hour,1,ca1.StartDate) 

from supportContacts --<< any table

CROSS APPLY (select
             dateadd(minute,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 3650) * 15 ,DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 3650), dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, getDate()), 0)))  
             ) as ca1 (StartDate)
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/14607